# Cloning a canvas and replacing the overlay image

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to clone a canvas object and then replace the overlay image on the cloned canvas with a different one. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
_canvas.clone(function(cloneCanvas) {
  cloneCanvas.scale = _canvas.scale;
  cloneCanvas = self.pdcZoom.resetZoomBeforeSave(cloneCanvas);
  var src = config.media_url + _sidesConfig[tester]["filename"];
  cloneCanvas.overlayImage = null;
  fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function(img) {
    img.set({
      width: parseFloat(_canvas.width),
      height: parseFloat(_canvas.height),
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      alignX: options.alignX || 'none', // none, mid, min, max
      alignY: options.alignY || 'none',
      meetOrSlice: options.meetOrSlice || 'meet', // meet,
      isrc: src,
      object_type: 'mask',
      price: options.price || 0
    });
    cloneCanvas.setOverlayImage(img, cloneCanvas.renderAll.bind(cloneCanvas));
    //self.hideLoadingBar();
  });
});
```

`_canvas` is the original canvas and the `cloneCanvas` is the new one.

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. However when I try to alert(cloneCanvas) I get null, because I set it to null beforehand. So the setoverlayImage is not being set at all. When I try to just use setOverlayImage without setting it to anything.

Comment: @Durga any thoughts?

Comment: You want to clone a canvas, and set in another canvas?

Comment: I want to clone the canvas and change the overlay image on the cloned canvas. @Durga

Answer (score 0):

To clone canvas use [canvas.toJSON()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON) and then load the json using [loadFromJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON).

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas("c1");
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50
}));

setOverlay('https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', canvas);

function setOverlay(url, can) {
  fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
    img.set({
      scaleX: can.width / img.width,
      scaleY: can.height / img.height,
      excludeFromExport: true,
      opacity:0.5
    })
    can.setOverlayImage(img);
    can.renderAll();
  })

}

function clone() {
  var json = canvas.toJSON();
  canvas1.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
    setOverlay('https://picsum.photos/200/400/?random', canvas1);
  })
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
<button onclick='clone()'>clone</button>
<canvas id='c1' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```